# How to Call getLatestPrice function Chainlink Price Feed

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chainlink

I'm trying to use the chainlink price feed. Are we supposed to type all of our code in the [PriceconsumerV3 contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/)? Can we use inheritance to access the value? I tried putting the PriceconsumerV3 contract and my contract in the same file. What is the conventional setup?

Answer (score 0):

To access chainlink data feeds you simply need to import the AggregatorV3 Interface into whatever contract you would like to have use them like this:

```js
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
```

Then initialize the exact data feed your contract is pointing to in the constructor like this:

```js
    constructor() {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }
```

Where `0x9326....331` is the address of the data feed we are pointing to.

You do not have to actually put the entire [example PriceConsumer contract](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/) from the Chainlink docs into your own contract. That is just an example to show you how to structure a contract to use data feeds as I explained above.

Answer (score 0):

Note the Rinkeby and Kovan Testnets are phased out which isn't well documented in Solidity and Chainlink tutorials.  Goerli as of now is the predominat Testnet with different contract addresses hope this helps:

Scroll down the page to find Goerli contract addresses

https://docs.chain.link/docs/data-feeds/price-feeds/addresses/#Goerli%20Testnet